# The usage of "From X point of view"

Tags: word-usage

I wrote this sentence:

> From Web accessibility/usability point of view, speech rendering of the main content can provide better access to web pages for visually impaired users.

Before I had written it as:

> In Web accessibility/usability, speech rendering of the main content can provide better access to web pages for visually impaired users.

It seems neither of them are natural, in what cases "from point of view" is used? How can I say my purpose in the above sentence? should I use **FOR web accessibility,....**?

---

**Update:** It seems I can write *from accessibility ( or usability) point of view*, can I write **from accessibility and usability point*s* of view**?

Comment: As far as I know, *point of view* is countable, so you need an article if you write *From an accessibility point of view*..

Comment: @DamkerngT. I have problem to start a sentence for a specific scope, in another sentence I wrote *In constrained devices like mobile phones,  presenting the main block can make browsing the page easier*, should I use "in", "for", "over" in this sentence?

Comment: And you can *eliminate excess verbiage*:   "Speech rendering of the main content can make web pages *accessible* to visually impaired users."  You seem to be deliberately avoiding concision.

Comment: @TRomano For the answer of question, I thought of "In the case of Web accessibility" how's that?

Comment: I have seen "form point of view of X, ...  " structure .

Comment: @Ahmad If it's *devices* in that example, I'd use *On*.

Comment: Ahmad, there is no "case" of web accessibility.  Accessibility is not a condition.

Comment: @TRomano agree, I think "in terms of" is better than "in case of .."

Comment: @TRomano ok, then please tell me, what should I say for this case? "Web accessibility" if once I want to say.

Comment: @DamkerngT. for this case, I prefer to say "in the case of constrained devices"

Comment: *In the case* is fine, because it's about *case*, not *device*.

Comment: Ahmad, I do not understand what you are trying to convey here with the word "case", which means *condition*:  In case of fire, call the fire department. I also don't understand "if once I want to say".  What idea are you trying to convey *beyond* the fact that text-to-speech makes web content accessible to the visually impaired?

Comment: @TRomano For example I need to categorize the applications of a software tool, sometimes I can't just count them, X, Y, Z, W... Maybe not here, but sometimes I would like to say, in This scope, applications are X, Y, in that scope applications are Z ,W. Now I just would like to know how can I use it for "Web accessiblity", Maybe you say there is no word for that. Forget this sentence, please give me an example how that could be used.

Comment: If you need to introduce a category you can use "under":  "*Under Web Accessibility*, there are tools such as text-to-speech, which makes content more accessible to visually impaired users, and main-content-extraction, which makes a page's textual content readable on smaller devices such as mobile phones."

Comment: your update is based on a misunderstanding: you cannot say "from accessibility point of view."

Comment: @sumelic I got that, just left it as a historical record, as other comments pointed that too.

Comment: It's a little over-written and foggy, Ahmad.

The raw concept is: blind people need screen readers.  It's not a case of "better access" because without a screen reader they have no access.

Comment: @MMacD good point! thank you! However, one may figure out another facility, however I can't think of any

Comment: Is this a lead-in to something, a follow-on, or is it supposed to stand alone?  What's the purpose of what you're writing?

Comment: @mmacd it's almost stand-alone in a scientific paper

Comment: *It seems I can write from accessibility ( or usability) point of view, can I write from accessibility and usability points of view?*  Yes, surely, why not?

Answer (score 1):

> From Web accessibility/usability point of view, speech rendering of the main content can provide better access to web pages for visually impaired users.

"Point" is a singular non-proper noun (with adjectives in front of it) and needs an article in front it, most likely "a." - *From a Web accessibility/usability point of view ...*

> In Web accessibility/usability, speech rendering of the main content can provide better access to web pages for visually impaired users.

*In + {body of knowledge}* is valid, i.e. "In philosophy, ... " or "In medicine, ... ".

In my opinion, the Web is relatively new in relation to other bodies of knowledge in the popular mind, so there are large groups of people who likely would not immediately understand that "Web accessibility/usability" is a body of knowledge.  So it could be a bit jarring unless your audience is only Web developers.

Comment: I came up with "In the case of Web accessibility"

Answer (score 0):

Consider a "setup, point" format such as this, Ahmad.

[setup:]Although the Web has some multimedia capability, it is still a strongly *visual* medium.  [point:]Browser software provides ways (larger type, stronger contrast) for people with limited vision to access the web visually, but for people without vision, a screen reader is needed.