# Is it acceptable to use a singular countable noun without a determiner?

Tags: definite-article

I have learned for the countable nouns I should use either a determiner or quantifier or use them plural, then I guess the following phrases are incorrect:

- DOM tree  --> the DOM tree
- in depth-first manner  --> in the depth-first manner
- in top-down manner --> in the top-down manner
- in hierarchical fashion --> in a hierarchical fashion
- from usability point of view --> from a usability point of view or from the usability point of view

Yet, I see these phrases in the web, can I assume most of them are used by mistake?

Comment: There are also nouns having zero article, however they work in case of general ideas. I have no idea about using zero article in your phrases.

Comment: @Cardinal yes but as I saw zero article is mostly for plural countable nouns or uncountable nouns, while here I am focused on singular countable nouns, I don't know their exceptions

Comment: "from usability point of view" is definitely wrong. Besides using an article, I'd put it the other way around: "from the point of view of usability."

Comment: actually, I see that you already asked about the use of " point of view": http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65185/the-usage-of-from-x-point-of-view

Comment: @Cardinal I am not sure, as your sentence may be said like "*Books, newspapers and computers have played a key role in public knowledge*"

Comment: @Ahmad You were right, they are mostly uncountable, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that in all those examples, a noun or another part of speech (adverb, abbreviation) is used as an adjective.  The article (definite or indefinite) is not used to modify the attribute ("adjective"), but the noun being defined.

> DOM tree == the tree [*representing*] DOM
>   in depth-first manner == in the manner "[*in which*] depth [*is explored*] first"
>   in hierarchical fashion == in the fashion [*that is*] hierarchical
>   from usability point-of-view == from the point-of-view of usability

As to validity of omitting the article, I think that in many cases it is OK because the idiomatic use of the "adjective" makes the definite article unnecessary.  For instance,

> in top-down manner

can't really be used with an '***a***' because there *aren't* several different "*top-down manners*" from which one can be chosen and spoken of, thus "top-down manner" becomes unique, uncountable so to speak, very much like a proper noun, except it's not written with a capital first letter.  Same with others, I think.

Comment: Oops! I just have reached a rule, you made me confused. Anyway, if you search them with and without article the number of them with article is much more. You mean that both cases are correct?

Comment: When in doubt, apply the article as you were taught. The only obvious error in all your examples was "from usability point of view", which definitely needs an article. The others could go either way.  And, as you are finding out, checking to see how others do it is not a reliable indicator of the "right" way. Much depends on _context_, which a simple search won't give you.  That is, it finds **how often** a phrasing is used, without regard to **where** or **how** it is used.